# ajax calback render form

Tags: forms, ajax, theming

I've problem when render form using ajax.
In my case link which should replece by form after clicking. But when I use form I have "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience." and nothing change. And if I callback sting all ok.

Someone know solution to render form?

```
function MYMODULE_ajax_response($type = 'ajax') {
    if ($type == 'ajax') {
        $form = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_my_form');
        $commands = array();
        $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#my-div'.$product_id, render($form));
        debug($commands);
        $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
        ajax_deliver($page);
    }
    else {
        $output = t("This is some content delivered via a page load.");
        return $output;
    }
}
```